# I have Updated Xcode to 7.3 but still it shows 7.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I have updated my Xcode to 7.3 from App Store. But still it shows 7.2.1. And for iOS 9.3 it shows "Could Not Found Developer Disk Image"

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading the latest Xcode and installing manually. You can download it here: http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3/Xcode_7.3.dmg

Trash your current copy of Xcode and drag this new one to your Applications folder then launch.

Comment: Also note it is not necessary to trash the old version (just in case you do want to go back) - you can have two versions of Xcode installed at once.

Comment: It works.. thanks.

Comment: The same problem occurred to me. I restarted App store and found 7.3 version again. Again updated and worked.